# JavaScript WebGL square grid of points, around center

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an algorithm in JavaScript that can take an input size, and make a Square grid of that size using points.

```
`for (j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
     for (x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
          points.push(j / 10, x / 10);
     }
 }`
```

With the above code I can easily make a square grid as desired, but obviously only in the positive section. What I'm stuck on is making (0,0) my center of the square and consistently making the square around that center. (I can't change my origin). When I draw it out I can't see any consistent pattern for drawing a square of points that go in both positive and negative direction without knowing the size of the grid ahead of time? Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain the problem more clearly?

Comment: @S.Serp So if there was an input of 2, it would create a 2x2 square grid but with points. Basically a 2x2 would have 9 points, creating the corners of the squares essentially.

Comment: you talked about the center, your explanation is not clear at all. It would be nice if you could draw some picture and explain clearly